# PyQt5 - Get the pixel color inside a QWidget

Tags: pyqt5

I made a QWidget and inside I made some other items like QLabels which display images.
Consider what is inside that parent Widget I was trying to get the color where I would click.

Searching I found this thread but it is a bit old and I am not able to translate it to Python.

thread:
https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/49693-How-to-get-color-of-pixel-or-point

code:

```
 QPixmap qPix = QPixmap::grabWidget(ui->myWidget);
         QImage image(qPix.toImage());
         QColor color(image.pixel(0, 1));
```

How would this translate this to PyQt5 if it is the correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`QPixmap.grabWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap-obsolete.html#grabWidget-1) is considered obsolete, and you should use [`QWidget.grab()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grab) instead.

```
    pixmap = self.someWidget.grab()
    img = pixmap.toImage()
    color = img.pixelColor(0, 1)
```